# What is the bare minimum needed to run an android GUI program on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, gui, android

I have grabbed an android x86 ubuntu "app" that runs android on top of linux.    How would I run that from a CLI only install of ubuntu, like ubuntu server?    Or what is the bare minimum needed to run this GUI program with the least overhead possible, as all of this runs on an intel atom.

Comment: You're going to need a GUI environment - in other words, X - to run a GUI app.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a lightweight GUI, such as [LXqt](https://lxqt.org/) or [XFCE](https://www.xfce.org/), as well as an [Android emulator](https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-android-emulators-for-linux-to-enjoy-android-apps-in-linux/), of which there are many.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the android emulator, should pull in all the dependencies you need for GUI.